# How to convert the following Nearest Neighbor recursive function to an iterative function

Tags: c++, loops, recursion

I'm currently trying to optimize the following nearest neighbor algorithm by converting it to an iterative function.

Note: d0, d1, d2, d, shortest, shortest_node is defined outside of the function to reduce memory usage
shortest is initialized to a large number, everything else to 0

```
void NearestNeighbor(Node * node, float vector[3], unsigned short depth)
{
    if (node == nullptr)
        return;

    d0 = node->vector[0] - vector[0];
    d1 = node->vector[1] - vector[1];
    d2 = node->vector[2] - vector[2];

    // distance without sqrt
    d = d0 * d0 + d1 * d1 + d2 * d2;

    // if d is less than the distance to the current closest node
    if (d < shortest)
    {
        shortest = d;
        shortest_node = node;
        // if [shortest] is equal to 0, we've found the nearest possible neighbor
        if (shortest == 0)
            return;
    }
    // % 3 is because the vector is 3 dimensional
    short diff = node->vector[depth % 3] - vector[depth % 3];

    // can't wrap my head around converting this to an iterative algorithm
    Nearest(diff > 0 ? node->l : node->r, vector, depth + 1);
    if (diff * diff < shortest)
        Nearest(diff > 0 ? node->r : node->l, vector, depth + 1);
}
```

I've tried by starting from an iterative tree traversal algorithm (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inorder-tree-traversal-without-recursion/) and modifying it to fit my algorithm, but I can't seem to figure out how to work around the conditional recursion.

After quite some time trying, I currently have a non working function: (Just blindly trying btw, I can't figure out how to approach the problem)

```
void NearestNeighbor_Iterative(Node * root, float vector[3])
{
    std::stack<Node *> s;
    Node * cur = root;
    bool e = false;
    unsigned short depth = 0;
    while (cur != NULL || s.empty() == false)
    {
        if(cur != NULL)
            e = true;

        while (cur != NULL)
        {
            d0 = cur->vector[0] - vector[0];
            d1 = cur->vector[1] - vector[1];
            d2 = cur->vector[2] - vector[2];

            d = d0 * d0 + d1 * d1 + d2 * d2;

            if (d < shortest)
            {
                shortest = d;
                shortest_node = root;

                if (shortest == 0)
                    break;
            }
        
            diff[depth] = cur->vector[depth % 3] - vector[depth % 3];

            s.push(cur);
            cur = diff[depth] > 0 ? cur->l : cur->r;
            depth++;
        }
        if (e)
            depth--;
        else
            depth -= 2;
        cur = s.top();
        s.pop();
        if (diff[depth] * diff[depth] < shortest)
        {
            e = false;
            cur = diff[depth] > 0 ? cur->r : cur->l;
            depth++;
        }
        else
        {
            cur = nullptr;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why do you think `std::stack<Node *> s` would perform any better than recursion?

Comment: Ah, sorry for using the wrong term,  English's not my first language, I probably misunderstood the term, Thank you for the correction!

Comment: I used a stack because I was following the sample from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ I don't know how it will fare against the recursive version, but I was taught that C/C++ performs iteration better than recursion in general, but I have no concrete evidence.

Comment: No sorry I think it was my mistake. You do process two branches although I don't quite understand why.

Comment: Iteration may be better than recursion, but dynamic storage allocation might just eat all this advantage.

Comment: I was looking to implement this https://youtu.be/ivdmGcZo6U8?t=120 , which is why I need to process both side of the branches, The if statement is also necessary because without it, a "false positive" result might sometimes get included.

Comment: For speed optimization, I was thinking about creating a static-stack depending on the size of the tree, which may help reduce the cost of dynamic allocation, if I'm able to get the iteration algorithm working, that is.

Comment: If you need speed, looking for a better algorithm is often more productive than looking for better micro-optimisations.

Comment: I need both speed and memory, I know I have to compromise one or the other, but I haven't decided on where to draw the line, I've tried some other algorithms to categorize a vector which are simpler like truncation (too much information lost), look up table (pure look up table is too memory intensive), brute force (too slow). Maybe it's because I'm quite close to the required spec that I'm willing to spend the extra effort.